# Easy way to colour ALL user input in terminal?

Tags: colors, terminal

I know that there is lots of info for colouring the output of certain commands, but I want to have a specific colour for *everything* I write into the Mac terminal.

It would allow me to have a special colour for everything I input - not the output, just the code I personally input - making it easy to scan the code to where the last command was. I want to find a way to do it without having to write a colour alias for every single command - A way that by default will implement a unique colour for everything I write in the terminal.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: BTW - in case this wasn't clear, I just want a single colour. I don't need anything fancy like different colours for different input. I simply want to locate the commands I wrote when scanning the terminal. I figure making them all one colour will make this easier.

Answer (score 0):

I have now sorted this...

Open your ~/.bash_profile in whatever editor you prefer.

Add the following code:

```
export PS1="\e[0;32m[\u@\h \W]\$ \e[m"
```

and save.

You will now see that your command prompt is coloured green, and it's super easy to find yourself in the terminal :)

Hope that's helpful for anyone trying to fix the same problem!

P.S> These instructions cover more than just the colour in the terminal... They also control what it shown in your command prompt. I'm afraid that it will need someone way more advanced at coding than me to decipher which bit refers to what... Sorry!